# Segmentation fault with Rails 5 app with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, segmentation-fault

I'm getting a weird issue with Rails that I've never encountered before. I put a Rails 5 app using Mongoid onto Google Compute Engine to play with the platform and I was doing some load testing. I used siege and a custom script I made that sends a request, waits for a response, and then sends another request, looping forever. My script is available here: https://gist.github.com/welkie/bf3efa62bab2194d4b679c1f69957d2a

The siege test fails 1-4 out of 50 transactions consistently and my script gets back a 500 response after running for about 20-100 request response cycles. The debug logs for Rails have a segmentation fault. That massive error message is available here: https://gist.github.com/welkie/e200760852917c68cc9de650362618d3

I thought this was a memory or CPU issue so I tried a high CPU GCE instance but the issue persisted. Then I thought it was a GCP issue so I threw the same app onto AWS and I get the exact same behaviour.

Has anybody encountered this before?

Update:

I've since performed a test on my local machine and I am not encountering this problem locally. I mimicked my setup, using Docker locally too. I only encountered it on AWS and GCP.

Update:

I've now also performed another test on GCP but this time without Docker and this time I'm not getting any segfaults. It's still using Puma. At this point the only combination I can pinpoint is using Puma with Docker on a cloud host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. This is a bug affecting Ruby 2.4:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-1202